# Does Google.com show UK websites to UK users

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, local-seo, search-results

**Example:**

I have a website:
www.example.co.uk And www.example.com which redirects to the former.

Let's say my niche idea has only 20 competitors in the world. All of these competitors are in the US mostly and a few other countries.

I'm going to be the first UK company to rival my abroad competitors. This means that ranking for my keywords will not be majorly hard.

**Question 1:**

If someone from the UK, goes on to www.google.**com**, and then searches my focus keyword. Will google recognise the user is from the UK and calculate that it may be more relevant to show the UK websites for this given keyword first or at least higher up?

**Question 2:**

If someone from the UK, goes on to www.google.**co.uk**, and then searches my focus keyword. Will google calculate that it may be more relevant to show the UK websites for this given keyword first or at least higher up?

**Myself:**

I am from the Uk however, when I search through google I always use the www.google.**com** domain, and because of this i thought of the questions mentioned above.

Comment: If I go to google.com it automatically redirects to google.co.uk so I don't think it is a major problem all UK visitors will be on google.co.uk from the start anyway (unless they are using a VPN in a different country).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1:** What you're asking about is called Geolocation - Google shows different results depending on the geographic region you're searching from/interested in. For example, if you're in the US but append your search with 'UK' it will show you the US rankings with a huge tilt toward UK based websites. This isn't to say it shows you a UK SERP - but the weight does change.

Regions are determined by the Google domain you use. For Google.com, it does indeed redirect to .co.uk when you're located in the UK. This isn't true for other English language searches - such as .ca or .ie.

**Question 2:** Yes Google will weight depending on the sites Region and the relevance to the users Region. If you don't explicitly set it, they guess based on server location, language, page language, etc. Because you've got a .co.uk site, it's automatically set for you. If you were using your .com you'd have to set your region in Webmaster to be sure to gain a UK region preference.

Comment: In addition, if you are logged onto Google with your account, such as Search Console login, Google tracks interest including location interest. Logged on or not, Google will use your IP address geo-location and will preference some sites that are near your location etc.